# What does iOS "Preparing Update..." mean?

Tags: ios, software-update

When my iOS has an update it downloads then spends a long, long time "**Preparing Update...**" before completing the install. Generally tens of minutes and often longer than half an hour or so (haven't precisely measured). If I disconnect from WiFi it pauses.

What is iOS doing during this "**Preparing Update**" phase and why does it require a WiFi connection?

Is there anything I can do to make it possible offline or faster so wifi interruption is less of a factor in getting it installed (which is often a problem when tethering via other devices, traveling, etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you also use Mac computers? If so you could look at [Content caching](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl9388ba1b/mac) to speed up software installation on your iPhone, iPad, Mac etc. As for the fact it pauses when on Wi-Fi, that's because an iOS upgrade (and any large update) cannot be downloaded via a cellular connection - it must be connected to the internet via Wi-Fi etc instead. And this is relevant because the process of **preparing** an update actually includes downloading file(s) from Apple's servers.

Comment: I always make sure to not be travelling etc to give the updating device a stable wifi connection.